# Unable to view stack and memory addresses in IDA Pro

Tags: ida, debugging, linux, elf

I am debugging a 32-bit ELF executable using remote GDB debugging option of IDA Pro. However, I am unable to view the contents of stack in the stack view. Also, the stack pointer value is: 0xFFFFD328

In the hex dump view, if I press G and enter the above address, it does not display. Similarly, in the stack view, I cannot scroll to this address or view it either.

The function prolog in the main function initializes the stack pointer as shown below:

```
lea     ecx, [esp+4]
and     esp, 0FFFFFFF8h
push    dword ptr [ecx-4]
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
push    ecx
sub     esp, 0Ch
```

Comment: Is that a userland or a kernel executable?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Stack View and you can sync with ESP or jump to ESP.

The second instruction may be misleading, but it's subtracting 8 from ESP not adding a very large value.

In Hex view, as with many windows in IDA, you can use register names instead of a linear address when you use the Go To command. You can press 'G', input 'esp' and press ENTER to jump to ESP.

Comment: The second instruction applies a bitmask to round esp down

Comment: This does not seem to answer the OP's question. I am encountering the same thing right now. Upon entry to `main`, the stack pointer is `0xFFFFD95C`, while the `stack view` only shows up through `0xFEFFFFFC`. Attempting to "sync with esp" or jump to esp will fail. Is there a way to add more memory such that the contents of the stack can be viewed?