# bad memory mapping in case of MEMORY dump IDA <-> WinDbg

Tags: ida, windbg, memory-dump

when I open the debug dump (IDA x64) , I don't have the memory ranges. Exactly like in this question:

[ESP out of range of "Stack View" in IDA](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16049/esp-out-of-range-of-stack-view-in-ida)

It used to be fine, but I don't have the menu edit-> "manual memory regions" as I am on IDA 7.4. (I guess)

I tried to add a segment and it didn't work!

windbg 10.0.18362.1

Comment: You're guessing you are using IDA 7.4 or you are guessing you don't have the menu item?

Comment: I guess that is the reason I don't have the menu. But it could be a configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following from idapython:

```
import ida_dbg
ida_dbg.edit_manual_regions()
```